# How to structure jquery ajax to be flexible to in and outputs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a one-page structured website. I am trying to use Ajax to update my data on user demand.
I am trying to figure out how to structure my ajax code, so that it will be flexible to my in and outputs = I want to run different function depending on the clicked link, and I want to return the right output to the right div.

HTML links:

```
<a href="#page-a" class="dbLink" data-variable="funcA">
<a href="#page-b" class="dbLink" data-variable="funcB">

<div id="page-a">
    <div id="a-result"></div>
</div>

<div id="page-b">
    <div id="b-result"></div>
</div>
```

JS, ajax (I am passing a data-variable along the link to controle the action):

```
$(document).on("click", ".dbLink", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theAction = $(this).attr("data-variable");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ini/functions.php',
        data: { action: theAction },
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(resp){
            if(resp.data){
                $(resp.target).html(resp.data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

functions.php:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';

function funcA($mysqli){
   $result = $mysqli->query("select * from database");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo $row['column'];
}

function funcB($mysqli){
   $result = $mysqli->query("select * from database2");
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   return $row['column'];
}

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
   $resp = null;
   switch($_POST['action']) {
    case "funcA":
        $resp->data = funcA($mysqli);
        $resp->target = "#page-a";
        break;
    case "funcB":
        $resp->data = funcB($mysqli);
        $resp->target = "#page-b";
        break;
    default:
        break;
  }
  echo json_encode($resp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add another data-* variable set to the id of the place you want to output the data. To control the format of the returned data provide the dataType option in the ajax options, and of course make sure the pointed to url actually outputs that type of data. dataType It will tell jQuery how to parse the incoming data.

```
var theContainer = $(this).attr("data-container");
...
dataType:"json" //or text, or xml etc etc
success: function(data){
   //if data is upposed to be json
   //and datType is set to json
   //data will be an object, same with xml
   //process data how you need to
   $("#"+theContainer).html(whateverYouHaveDone);
}
```

If you need to control the target of the returned data within your php script then turn your returned data into json and send the selector for the target to it

```
$resp = new stdClass;
switch($_POST['action']) {
   case "funcA":
      $resp->data = funcA($mysqli);
      $resp->target = "#someContainer";
      break;
   case "funcB":
      $resp->data = funcB($mysqli);
      $resp->target = "#someContainer";
      break;
   default:
      break;
}

echo json_encode($resp);
```

Then in your ajax success

```
success: function(resp){
    if(resp.data){
       $(resp.target).html(resp.data);
    }
}
```

And of course set `dataType:"json"`

To return just the mysql row, do the same thing as above but in the ajax success `resp.data` will be an object. So just access the properties of `resp.data` with the column names of the row

```
success: function(resp){
    if(resp.data){
       //if say you have a column named "username"
       var username = resp.data.username;
    }
}
```

Comment: aha i see. say will select a whole row in my php request, how can i pass that back to the ajax, so jquery understand it?

Comment: very nice! this makes a lot of sense. of course treat the return as a json object. i will give it a shot now! appreciate it!

Comment: aha, very nice with the selection of json data.

Comment: i dont seem to get any output in my div. Do you have a sec to see my updated code?

Comment: `$row['column'];` is `column` an actual column name for the row?

Comment: ive tried to simply have alert(resp) in the success: - acutally that doesnt even pop up

Comment: you have `$resp = null;`, it needs to be an object, `$resp = new stdClass;` otherwise your script is going to be erroring out with trying to set property on null

Comment: doesnt do anything :/ should i have the function echo or return?

Comment: also note you are echoing the column and not returning it in your funcA function Make sure to check your error logs to make sure your script is not erroring out. Look in the network tab of the developer console (usually F12 to bring it up) and look for the request to the script and see what it shows as the response and make sure it is correct

Comment: in console it looks fine:200 and everything. ive added contentType: "application/json", to the ajax, it seems to make the load run faster, but still no output..

Comment: NOW IM GETTING SOMETHING! :) i had the echo json and $resp = new stdClass; inside the if(isset)

Comment: dont i need to parse the json when in get it back?

Comment: if you have the dataType set to json no, jquery will do that for you, use an error callback along with the success callback, it will be triggered if there is an error. `error: function(xhr,message){ alert(message); }`

Comment: good idea. when i do inside succes: function(resp){alert(resp.data);} i get undefined?

Comment: sounds like your data isnt getting set, you said it started working after you moved the json echo outside the `if(isset)`, `var_dump($_POST)` to make sure it contains your action variable. Otherwise your `default` case might be being triggered, and again not setting any data

Comment: when i have var_dump($_POST) i get parseerror - i guess its the ajax error handler fired.

Comment: thats expected, you need to look at the response, in the network tab click on the request and click on the response tab it should show the raw data being sent back.

Comment: response is array(0) {}{}

Comment: looks like your action isnt being sent so `$_POST['action']` isnt set, alert your theAction variable before the ajax call and make sure it is being set

Comment: the variable contains the string when i alert the variable. should i quotes around theAction like {action: ''+theAction+''} ?

Comment: i added $resp->data = "something"; to default switch aswell. to see if that was fired - it isnt?

Comment: no, you dont need quotes in a object literal when using a variable for the value. Back in the network tab and in the request does it show the action being sent in the request headers

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", ".dbLink", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theAction = $(this).attr("data-variable");
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ini/functions.php',
        data: { action: theAction },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data){
            $(target).html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: but how can i controle the $(target) to whatever i have run in functions.php? i mean the target depend on the request

Comment: @MacLuc sorry im not sure what you mean. My example will add the output of functions.php to whatever div is linked in the href attribute of the clicked link - so functionB outputs to div#page-b

Comment: @MacLuc Oh you mean that you dont want to just display the results in the div?  Perhaps you display the result of funtionA in a list, and functionB in a table? Is this what you mean?

Comment: ahh i see, missed that part! that was what i was after. can you give me any tips on how to pass for instance a whole row from my php to the jquery. now i just echo the result as you can see.

Comment: @MacLuc you have a couple of options - you can build the html in php then just drop it into the div with jQuery using .html(data) like above, or you can build an array/stdclass in php, and json_encode it so jquery can access the properties. If you just want to output html the 1st option is the easiest

Comment: @MacLuc if you decide to go with the second option, make sure you set the correct php header for json

Comment: if i just build the html in the php file, will it be outputted to my actual html page? should i then have the url in the ajax as self and then run it from there?

Comment: @MacLuc Whatever you return from php, is recieved by the javascript, and handled however you choose. In the code above, the return data is displayed in a div. So if you built html in the php function like this: <h2>hello Mac</h2> and returned that, you would get <div id="page-a"><h2>hello Mac</h2></div>

Comment: ah now i get the point. would there be any point in having the ajax url just as SERVER SELF and then just run function from mypage.php and output it directly?

Comment: If you like, though you will have to add logic in the php to make sure you ONLY return the json, and dont re render the page as well. Probably easier to keep the php separate.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this.
I see you have understood the custom data-* attributes. I would add one more attribute: data-target=""

```
<a href="#page-a" class="dbLink" data-variable="funcA" data-target="a-result">
<a href="#page-b" class="dbLink" data-variable="funcB" data-target="b-result">

<div id="page-a">
    <div class="a-result"></div>
</div>

<div id="page-b">
    <div class="b-result"></div>
</div>
```

Then inside your JQuery, you do like you do with your data-variable, only that you add the new data-* attribute:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dbLink", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var theAction = $(this).attr("data-variable");
    var theTarget = $( this ).attr("data-target");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ini/functions.php',
        data: { action: theAction },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(){
          /* Here you have to change the data[] to match the JSON return from your PHP-script. You can of course do it without JSON, but I would use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php on an array from PHP.*/
          $("input[class="+ theTarget +"]").html( data["foo"][0]["bar"] );
        }
    });
});
```

If you want to play with a real life example, I made this fiddle for another guy on stack overflow a while back: http://jsfiddle.net/Olavxxx/Mu66h/

Put a number in the left box (like 5006), it's postal codes. The target then is the postal adress in the right input box. The concept is very much the same as you are after, with data-targets.